# Do I have to chain targeting in DFP, or can they be individual lines?

Tags: google-dfp

In DFP, I have something like this:

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting('age', ['35to44']).setTargeting('gender', ['female']);
```

Do I have to chain those `setTargeting` statements, or can I do something like this:

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting('age', ['35to44']);
googletag.pubads().setTargeting('gender', ['female']);
```

The latter is easier for some programmatic targeting we're attempting to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do both.

See the first example on [this page](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1638622).

I also use the non chaining method in my [jQuery DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/blob/master/jquery.dfp.js#L153) plugin and it works really well.